# Unable to send email from microsoft graph api

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to send system generated email to users to notify them about change in inventory. But I am unable to do so with client secret login. I get the access token correctly. But email sending fails all the time

```
import requests
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

# Microsoft Graph API endpoints
graph_api_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0"
send_mail_url = f"{graph_api_url}/users/admin@example.com/sendMail"

# Azure App credentials
client_id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
tenant_id = "YOUR_TENANT_ID"

# Recipient's email address
to_email = "recipient@example.com"

# Construct the email message
subject = "Test Email"
body = {
    "content": f"Hello, this is a test email sent from Python using Microsoft Graph API.",
    "contentType": "Text"
}
message = {
    "message": {
        "subject": subject,
        "body": body,
        "toRecipients": [{"emailAddress": {"address": to_email}}]
    }
}

# Authenticate using Microsoft Graph API
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)

token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])

if "access_token" in token_response:
    access_token = token_response["access_token"]
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    # Send the email
    response = requests.post(send_mail_url, headers=headers, json=message)

    if response.status_code == 202:
        print("Email sent successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to send email. Status code: {response.status_code}")
else:
    print("Failed to acquire access token.")
```

Error that I am getting is
{"error":{"code":"MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI","message":"The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise."}}'

Comment: Could you include what error you are facing and check whether the token has `Mail.Send` permission by decoding it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms)?

Comment: I have edited my question because I won't be using /me/sendMail instead I will be sending it from admin email address so it will be /users/admin@example.com/sendMail. Secondly the response that I am getting right now is Response [404] that's it.

Comment: Instead of printing status code, could you try getting response content modifying like this `print(f"Failed to send email. Status Message: {response.content}")` to know more details about error?

Comment: {"error":{"code":"MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI","message":"The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise."}}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that, the error usually occurs if the user does not have **valid** Office 365 license assigned to them, that is **required** to send mails.

I have one user named **`Demo Sri`** without having any **licenses** assigned like below:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment with this user mail, I too got **same error** as below:

```py
import requests
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

# Microsoft Graph API endpoints
graph_api_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0"
send_mail_url = f"{graph_api_url}/users/demosri@example.com/sendMail"

# Azure App credentials
client_id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
tenant_id = "YOUR_TENANT_ID"

# Recipient's email address
to_email = "sri@example.com"

# Construct the email message
subject = "Test Email"
body = {
    "content": f"Hello, this is a test email sent from Python using Microsoft Graph API.",
    "contentType": "Text"
}
message = {
    "message": {
        "subject": subject,
        "body": body,
        "toRecipients": [{"emailAddress": {"address": to_email}}]
    }
}

# Authenticate using Microsoft Graph API
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)

token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])

if "access_token" in token_response:
    access_token = token_response["access_token"]
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    # Send the email
    response = requests.post(send_mail_url, headers=headers, json=message)

    if response.status_code == 202:
        print("Email sent successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to send email. Status Message: {response.content}.")
else:
    print("Failed to acquire access token.")
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to assign active **Office 365 license** to the user like this:

[image]

When I ran the same code again after assigning license, I got **response** without any error like this:

```py
import requests
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

# Microsoft Graph API endpoints
graph_api_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0"
send_mail_url = f"{graph_api_url}/users/demosri@example.com/sendMail"

# Azure App credentials
client_id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
tenant_id = "YOUR_TENANT_ID"

# Recipient's email address
to_email = "sri@example.com"

# Construct the email message
subject = "Test Email"
body = {
    "content": f"Hello, this is a test email sent from Python using Microsoft Graph API.",
    "contentType": "Text"
}
message = {
    "message": {
        "subject": subject,
        "body": body,
        "toRecipients": [{"emailAddress": {"address": to_email}}]
    }
}

# Authenticate using Microsoft Graph API
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=client_secret)

token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])

if "access_token" in token_response:
    access_token = token_response["access_token"]
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    # Send the email
    response = requests.post(send_mail_url, headers=headers, json=message)

    if response.status_code == 202:
        print("Email sent successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to send email.Status Message: {response.content}.")
else:
    print("Failed to acquire access token.")
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in **`Sent Items`** of user where mail sent successfully as below:

[image]

Comment: How to setup do_not_reply kind of thing with microsoft. I am asking this because I don't want user to authenticate the app. Also in my tenant I have 10 users but this token works only for the admin user and not others. How to get access token for other users

Comment: Note that, generating token with client credentials flow does not involve any user interaction. This token with `Mail.Send` permission of Application type works for all users in the tenant. If it is working for only admin user, I believe you assigned license to only admin user. To make it work for all other users, you need to assign **Office 365 license** to all users.